# Sending QVector of QSharedPointers through queued Qt signal-slot connection

Tags: c++, qt

I've encountered problem when I've tried to send QVector > between threads through queued signal-slot connection (Tester is my class that inherits QObject)

When I try to simply connect signal\slot with such QVector as argument programm tells during run that this metatype should be registered (though QVector, QSharedPointer and class inherited from QObject should be registered automatically.

I've tried adding

```
typedef QVector<QSharedPointer<Tester> > TestPointerVector;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TestPointerVector);
```

after declaration of Tester class and add to main()

```
qRegisterMetaType<TestPointerVector>();
```

In that case I have compiling errors in qmetatype.h и qtypeinfo.h telling me that QVector > is incomplete type and that sizeof of such vector can't be calculated.

What is right way to do this register metatype thing?

My testing main() looks as follow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<TestPointerVector>();
    Receiver* rcv = new Receiver(0);
    Emitter* emt = new Emitter(0);
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    QObject::connect(rcv, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(rcv, SIGNAL(finished()), rcv, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(emt, SIGNAL(send(TestPointerVector)), rcv, 
    SLOT(receive(TestPointerVector)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    rcv->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
    emt->process();

    while(!thread->isFinished())
        continue;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `#include <QVector>`

Comment: @jesper-juhl Nope, QVector and QSharedPointer are already included, so problem isn't here.

Comment: Not sure if that affects the thing in the topic but: `while(!thread->isFinished())
        continue;` is just wrong. You prevent the code from getting to main thread code event loop and not clear why the `thread` finishes before that.

Comment: @AlexandrVX it has nothing to do with my problem, but still thanks, that code was preventing my program from reaching end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem, it wasn't in qRegisterMetaType part. Problem was that I was using Qvector<...> in signal\slot signatures, I've changed it to const QVector<...>& and everything started working.

And if QSharedPointer is deleted in emitter thread it'd still be received by receiver and data won't be corrupted (what I was trying to test by this example).